# How would I play audio output through a virtual audio input device? (Cable Input)

Tags: java, audio

I'm very new to programming and Java in general, but I was curious on how I'd go about doing something specific.

I'm reading this tutorial on how to capture audio (in my case, through my default audio device - my headphones), and then play it back through the same device.

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/120-javax-sound/917-capturing-audio-with-java-sound-api.html

It's a great tutorial but to be honest I'm still learning how it works.

I do have one question for you guys, how would I play back the audio through my CABLE input VB-Audio Virtual Cable device

[image: This separate audio device]

using a SourceDataLine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

REM: Voicemeeter virtual audio board and virtual audio mixer, is delivered with Voicemeeter Remote API, including AUDIO API (through standard DLL)... feel free to download SDK there: http://vbaudio.jcedeveloppement.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=346